# My manually created power() function shows TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I was solving this on a platform where we were not allowed to use the in-built function. It works just fine in Python IDLE but shows the above error in ONLINE compiler. Please rectify this.

#Function to calculate x^n in a recursive way

```
def power(x,n: int) -> int:
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*power(x,n-1)
```

It shows this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: can you provide the online compiler link too? seems fine to me

Comment: It works well inside the online compiler, please send the error link